# Could not open input file: shell/compiler.php

Tags: magento2.3.2

I am using the following command from command line to check compiler state in magento2.3.2

```
php -f shell/compiler.php -- state
```

I found this in the following url
https://magehit.com/blog/how-to-disable-magento-2-compiler-from-command/

But I am getting an error while running the command

Could not open input file: shell/compiler.php
[image]

I know it has something to do with file paths but could not understand what, please let me know what changes I shall make to make it work.

Comment: Magento 2 does not have any folder name 'shell/compiler``. if u have hitting wrong file

Comment: No such file is there on magento root